# getDmlFieldNames returns Field Label in Visualforce, but field API Name in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

As the subject suggests, when we run the code below in the developer console, the method `getDmlFieldNames()` returns the field API name.

```
try{
    upsert new Contact();
}catch(System.DmlException e){
    Integer numErrors = e.getNumDml();
    system.debug('numErrors:' + numErrors);
    for(Integer i=0;i<numErrors;i++) {
        System.debug('getDmlFieldNames=' + e.getDmlFieldNames(i)); //['LastName']
        System.debug('getDmlMessage=' + e.getDmlMessage(i));// Required fields are missing: [LastName]
    }
}
```

However, when we call the same code from from a `@RemoteAction` in a Visualforce page, we get the following:

```
getDmlFieldNames(i) //['Last Name']
getDmlMessage(i) // Required fields are missing: [Last Name]
```

As you can see, when the same code is executed from within a Visualforce page, the `getDmlFieldNames()` method returns the field API Label, whereas when we execute the code from the anonymous developer console context, we get the API Name.

We though this might be an issue related to the @RemoteAction annotation, however calling the same method annotated with `@RemoteAction` in the anonymous dev console again returns the field API Names.

We also tried using the `getDmlFields()` method from the `DMLException` class, but it always returns null.

Can anyone explain why the context impacts the return of the `getDmlFieldNames()` method on the `DMLException` class?